# ASCII decoding using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ascii, version, decode

I am using Python 2.7 (due to toolchains dependency :-( )

```
Input String = 'F1 88 52 45 4D 41 2D 33 43 37 38 32 2D 42 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00'

Output String = REMA-3C782-BB
```

Please help me in decoding the ASCII string(in hex) to the Output String as above.

This below code throws error:

```
BResponse = 'F1 88 52 45 4D 41 2D 33 43 37 38 32 2D 42 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00'                      
BResponse = BResponse.decode('ASCII')
```

Comment: try: `codecs.decode(BResponse.replace(b" ",b""),"hex")`

Comment: First two bytes are not ASCII. The string decodes to `'\xf1\x88REMA-3C782-BB\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'` in binary, `\xf1` and `\x88` are not ASCII characters (and `\x00` probably is just a rubbish, null bytes to pad to expected length).

Comment: *I am using Python 2.7 (due to toolchains dependency :-( )* then consider adding `python-2.7` tag to your question

Comment: I dded the tag.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're discarding non-ascii characters, you can use [`string.printable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.printable) in order to look for characters you don't want in your output.

```py
import string

def parse_response(response):
    return ''.join([chr(int(hex_letter, 16))
                    if chr(int(hex_letter, 16)) in string.printable
                    else ''
                    for hex_letter in response.split(' ')])
```

---

Making it return what we intended:

```py
BResponse = 'F1 88 52 45 4D 41 2D 33 43 37 38 32 2D 42 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00'
print parse_response(BResponse)
```

```
REMA-3C782-BB
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way

```
cipher = '52 45 4D 41'  # this should give REMA
plain = ''.join(['%c' % int(i,16) for i in cipher.split()])
print plain
```

gives output

```
REMA
```

*(tested in Python 2.7.18)*

Comment: This worked for me.. Many thanks. could you please explain  for i in cipher.split() it does?

Comment: `.split` method of `str` does *Return a list of the words in the string S, using sep as the delimiter string.(...)If sep is not specified or is None, any whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are removed from the result.*